# How to change required msg for dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I set the required attribute to the dropdown list. Now I submit the form without selecting any option of the drop-down it'll give me error msg like "Please select an item in the list."

I want to change this msg ? how to do that ??
HTML Code

```
<select required  id="doc_type">
```

Comment: Do not post question without search it on site. please take care of that.

Comment: add oninvalid="setCustomValidity('your message')"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use HTML5 event `oninvalid`

Try this :

```
<select required  id="doc_type" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please select an item in the list')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I've never used it before, do you know a way to add a custom CSS class to the message for custm styling? I've tried using `:required` in my CSS file with various selectors, but no joy

Comment: Thank you it really helps me in critical time :)